# Each.value cannot be used here

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm receiving the below error:

```
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
│ unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
│ its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
│ configuration to work around this error.
```

I want to use a for_each loop with each.value to shorten my code. I've added this to the variables:

```
variable "log_categories" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["AZFWApplicationRule", "AZFWApplicationRuleAggregation", "AZFWDnsQuery", "AZFWFqdnResolveFailure", "AZFWIdpsSignature", "AZFWNatRule", "AZFWNatRuleAggregation", "AZFWNetworkRule", "AZFWNetworkRuleAggregation", "AZFWThreatIntel", "AzureFirewallApplicationRule", "AzureFirewallDnsProxy", "AzureFirewallNetworkRule", "AllMetrics"]
}
```

And this is where I use the for.each loop:

```
  log {
      for_each = toset(var.log_categories)
      category = each.value
      retention_policy {
          days    = 30
          enabled = false
      }
  }
}
```

Can't figure out what is wrong. I already tried using each.key instead of each.value, but also not working

Comment: Are you trying to implement a dynamic block: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks?

Comment: Yes I think so. I did not use this manual, but it seems like I'm doing that. Sorry I'm quite new to Terraform.

Comment: After using the correct syntax, does it work as expected?

Comment: Many thanks! It is working now. I will save the documentation for later. I learned something new today!

Answer (score 4):

I had to create a dynamic block in order for it to work:

```
  dynamic "log" {
      for_each = toset(var.log_categories)
      content {
        category = log.value
        retention_policy {
          days    = 30
          enabled = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you saved the night

Answer (score -1):

But first check that you used "for_each" and not say "foreach"....